# How write User Input Data to External Text File?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to take the test scores the user inputs and write to an external text file. Then have the application read off the values from the and calculate the average. However, I am unsure as to how to implement the python syntax within the loop and the functions.  I've attempted to utilize my resources to get a better idea of how to do this, but I've been having some trouble understanding how python handles external files.  In addition, would using append be better than write in this scenario?
Current Syntax:

```
 def testAvgCalculation():
        #Variables
        total = 0
        total_quiz = 0
        while True:
        #User Input and Variable to stop loop
            inpt = input("Enter score: ")
            if inpt.lower()== 'stop':
                break
        #Data Validation
            try:
                if int(inpt) in range(1,101):
                     total += int(inpt)
                     total_quiz += 1
                else:
                    print("Score too small or Big")
            except ValueError:
                print("Not a Number")
        return total, total_quiz


    def displayAverage(total, total_quiz):
        average = total / total_quiz

        print('The Average score is: ', format(average, '.2f'))
        print('You have entered', total_quiz, 'scores')
    #Main Function
    def main():
        total, total_quiz = testAvgCalculation()
        displayAverage(total, total_quiz)
    #Run Main Function
    main()
```

Comment: This is quite broad. What have you tried? What part did you particularly get stuck on? Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky as heck, but I tried to work with what was already there. I split the data validation section of the original function off into a separate function. In `main()` it returns its value `counter`, which keeps track of how many values were entered, to `calculate_average()`, which then reads the file line by line until `counter` becomes 0, which means it's about to read the word "stop" (which allows EOF recognition via the 'and' in the if statement), performs the calculation and returns its values.

```
def write_file():
    #Variables
    counter = 0

    file = open("Scores.txt", "w")

    while True:
    #User Input and Variable to stop loop
        inpt = input("Enter score: ")
        file.write(inpt + "\n")

        if inpt.lower()== 'stop':
            file.close()
            break
        counter += 1
    return counter

def calculate_average(counter):
    total = 0
    total_quiz = counter
    scores = open("Scores.txt", "r")
    s = ""
    try:
        while counter > 0 and s != 'stop':
            s = int(scores.readline())
            if int(s) in range(1,101):
                 total += int(s)
                 counter -= 1
            else:
                print("Invalid data in file.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid data found")
    return total, total_quiz

def displayAverage(total, total_quiz):
    average = total / total_quiz

    print('The Average score is: ', format(average, '.2f'))
    print('You have entered', total_quiz, 'scores')
#Main Function
def main():
    total, total_quiz = calculate_average(write_file())
    displayAverage(total, total_quiz)
#Run Main Function
main()
```

NOTE: the file is created initially in write mode which overwrites the file each time so you never need a new one. if you want to keep a record you might like to change it to append, though you'll need to manage extracting the proper lines from among old input.

Not pretty at all, but should give you an idea of how to accomplish what you were going for.